# About Kurosh-Ore theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, lattice-orders

Where can I find the proof of Kurosh-Ore theorem in lattice theory? 
The statement of this theorem is:

> Let $L$ be a modular lattice with $0$ and $1$ that satisfies both chain conditions. Then for any element $a$ in the lattice, any two decompositons of $a$ into independent and indecomposable elements can be put in 1-1 correspondence.

In Jacobson's book (GTM30 p204), he has mentioned this theorem without proof.

Comment: This theorem is proved in a lot of books (that you could have found by googling): https://books.google.ro/books?id=Ll0JXd11SW0C&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=Kurosh-Ore+theorem&source=bl&ots=TW-RQhvN9v&sig=WsRzC6oH_q6L--4kcHr6i93VFFc&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYuND49IHKAhXBcQ8KHQ7aBAkQ6AEILjAJ#v=onepage&q=Kurosh-Ore%20theorem&f=false

Comment: @user26857 Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also asked on MO: [About Kurosch-Ore theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/227217). You might have a look at other discussions about [meta-tag:cross-posting] as well, but in my opinion [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) provides a very reasonable advice.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the book Gabor Szasz - Introduction to Lattice Theory, Academic Press, N.Y., 1963 for proof of Kurosh-Ore theorem and refer the book P. Crawley and R.P, Dilworth - Algebraic Theory of Lattices, Prentice - Hall Inc., N. J., 1973, for proof of the Ore's theorem